# "someone eats too much"

Tags: phrase-request

> It seems **someone eats too much**. [meaning - "constantly"]
>
> It seems **someone has been eating too much**. [meaning - "we all see your weight"]

Is it natural to use that phrase, when you say it to someone who has some overweight? Perhaps you use that phrase only in certain tense, so I wrote two tenses that are logical for me (with their meaning).

Comment: Yes, _he eats too much_ means that he does so habitually, _he has been eating too much_ suggests that he has put on weight recently.

Comment: _It seems someone eats too much. [meaning - "constantly"]_ - do you mean they are eating all of the time (24 hours each day?)

Comment: @Michael Harvey, It was said figuratively.